# How to use variables in Python SQL query?

Tags: python, sql, syntax

I'm using some copy-pasted code to do SQL queries on a MySQL DB through Python/Flask. I'm not familiar with it and it's telling me the way I'm trying to input a variable is not the correct syntax.

My code runs a query to see if an email already exists.

The problem code:

```
def check_if_exists(val):
    import mysql.connector
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host=0.0.0.0", port=3306, user="username", passwd="password", db="testDB")
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    query = """SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = val"""
    result = cursor.execute(query)
    print(result)
```

It's assuming `val` is a column, but I want it to use the function argument instead.

```
result = check_if_exists('random@email.com')
>>> True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `%s` as a placeholder for the bound value:

```
query = """SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = %s"""
result = cursor.execute(query, (val,))
```