# How can I use a variable inside the where clause?

Tags: python, mysql

Let's say that I have four variables named a,b,c,d which I am getting as input from the user and I want to have such query in my application:

```
Select * 
from TABLE 
where (TABLE.FIELD = 'a' OR a = null) 
AND (TABLE.FIELD = 'b' OR b = null) ..
```

Is there a way to bind my variable like this inside the query? I am using MySQL and Python.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55556120/how-to-use-variables-in-python-sql-query

Comment: This is not exactly what I am trying to achieve. This example shows how to dynamically pass value to SQL query, whereas, I would like to have a null check of the variable inside the where clause.

Comment: Do you want to assign the variable inside the clause? Normally you would just use SET outside the query and then check that variable in the query clause.

Comment: Not exactly the assignment but kind of having an if clause inside the query statement. value of `a` won't be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a variable using SET outside the query, depending on how you receive the user input.
Then check the variables inside the query with IS NULL:

```
SET @a := my_val;

SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE (TABLE.FIELD = @a OR @a IS NULL)...;
```

Doing this, in the case where variable a is null, you would get the whole table from the query.

You could also make a stored procedure that checks the variables for null before querying. In a stored procedure you can use if conditions for instance.